# sql store the data in the column wise

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   id user_id  apt_id name   value datetime
    1  1        1      bp     109   ....
    2  1        1      sugar  180   ....
    3  2        2      bp     170   ....
```

I am trying to create the table in this approach because, the patient column is not the standard one, sometimes patient will be store the bp and sugar, sometime only bp.

Am i right in creating the design. If right, how to get the records of single patient.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, userid is your patientid in your scenario, in that case, use the below query to get the single patient record,

```
select * from Patienttable where user_id = '1'
```

Here you will get the single patient record. i.e., for user_id = 1

**Output:**

```
id user_id  apt_id name   value datetime
1  1        1      bp     109   ....
2  1        1      sugar  180   ....
```

**Note:** You can change as you want instead of **1**

Answer (score 0):

Others may disagree, but I wouldn't do it this way, unless you had several changing symptoms that you collect at different appointments.  If it's a small collection (some of which are not collected), I would just add them as columns to the appointment table, and leave the sugar column as NULL when it's not collected.

```
   user_id  apt_id bp   sugar datetime
    1        1     109   180    ....
    2        1     170          ....
```

The model you're proposing is a variant of Entity-Attribute-Value design, which has some strengths and some weaknesses.  Aaron Bertrand had a [good writeup of when an EAV design is useful](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway), and what the costs are for that design.  Based on the scenario you described, I don't think it's the best fit.

Comment: Yeah, but that's OK; databases can handle NULL :)